# Inserting Nodes into a priority queue java

Tags: java, priority-queue

Hi im trying to get all the nodes I create into the pq so i can order them in terms of weight and then remove the first two items (the smallest) so i can build a huffman tree which is a specialized version of a Binary tree whats the best way to do this? Thanks

```
public class Main {

    public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String inputFileName = args[0];
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

        // read in the data and do the work here
        // read a line at a time to enable newlines to be detected and allowed for

        while(in.hasNext()){
            CharacterMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new CharacterMap<Character, Integer>();
            char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            int c_count = 0;
            for (Character c : chars) {
                c_count += 1;
                if (hashMap.containsKey(c)) {
                    hashMap.put(c, hashMap.get(c) + 1);
                } else {
                    hashMap.put(c, 1);
                }
        }

            PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(new Comparator<Node>() {

            for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()){

                Node n = new Node();

                int f = entry.getValue();
                String c = entry.getKey();
                n.setWeight(f);
                n.setCharacter(c);

                n.setLeftChild(null);
                n.setRightChild(null);
                pq.add(n);
            }

        reader.close();

        String outputFileName = args[1];
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFileName);
        writer.write("Input file " + inputFileName + "  Huffman algorithm\n\n");

        // write out the results here

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        writer.write("\nElapsed time: " + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You appear to have done it already, on a quick scan of the code. What's the question?

Comment: Once i add them im not sure how to get the queue to order them in terms of weight one of the nodes instance variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the Java implementation of a priority queue to order your nodes by weight, you have to make your node class implement the "comparable" interface. This means putting a "compareTo" method in your node class and defining the comparison by weight, e.g:

```
private static class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    public int compareTo(Node n) {
        if(this.weight < n.weight){
            return -1;
        }else if(this.weight > n.weight){
            return 1;
        }else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  will the nodes automatically be inserted in order of weight when i do pq.add(n)? so i can just do pq.remove() to get the smallest weight?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Java's implementation of a Priority Queue is actually a [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). So when an item is added, it is compared against it's parent/child, and "bubbled" to the it's correct position.